# Issue in displaying the ongoing event and current events in the post

Tags: php, date

I am developing a consultancy website which has event to it. I am using ACF for generating event

Firstly the event consists of 3 things,

1. Past Events
2. Ongoing Events + current events + upcoming events

I have successfully generated a Past event and upcoming event for the events post, but my question is I am adding a ribbon for the posts to show  is the post is upcoming or ongoing or past or current.

In code I successfully generate a upcoming event and past event, but, I am unable to show the current event and ongoing event in the ribbon

the ribbon is like this

[image]

I added the following code to generate these ribbon

```
                        <div class="ribbon">
                                    <?php 
                                 

                                    $event_date = get_field('event_date');

                                    $events_date = new DateTime($event_date);
                                    $event_timestamp = $events_date->getTimestamp();
                                    
                                    
                                     //echo 

                                     if( $event_timestamp <= time()){

                                        $ribbon = "Past Event";
                                       

                                     }else{
                                        $ribbon = "Upcoming Event";
                                       
                                     }

                                     ?>
                                      <span><?php echo $ribbon; ?></span>
                                  </div>
```

for the ongoing event and the current event, there might be some thing which I should add in the above code but I cannot figure it out. Can U guys Please Help me to solve this issue

***Note** Also for the today date, my ribbon is showing past event and I don't why it is showing this.***

I too research the following stack overflow of these type but none of them work :(
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622370/php-how-to-check-if-a-date-is-today-yesterday-or-tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I Figured it out,

***But I have done soo many things that I don't know Is this a good approach or not also I want too simplify my process can anybody help me with this ??***

**Condition Meets**

Suppose Today Date is **April 12 - 2021**

- April 9 - April 10 => Past Events
- April 9 - April 12 => Ongoing Events
- April 12 - April 18 => Ongoing Events
- April 15 - April 18 => Upcoming Events
- April 11 - April 11 => Past Events
- April 8 - April 18 => Ongoing Events

**Code**

```
<?php
              $event_start_date = get_field('event_date'); //get event start date
              $event_end_date = strtotime(get_field('event_end_date')); // convert event date to strtotime
              $current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
              $curr_date=strtotime($current_date); //get current date

                    $the_date=strtotime($event_start_date); //convert event start date to strtotime
                
                $diff=floor(($curr_date-$the_date)/(60*60*24)); //cal for diff between two strtotime - output on float ie float(-1) or float(1)


                $date_s = date_create($current_date); 


                $date_e = date_create(get_field('event_end_date'));

                $difference_date = date_diff($date_s,$date_e); //get difference of two  dates result is shown on -1 day or 2 day

               
                $diff_days = $difference_date->format("%R%a"); // get the value of two difference date

if($event_end_date <  $curr_date  ){ // condition to check April-18 < April 12 

                  echo "Past Event";

                        if($diff == 0){ //condition to check April 12 == April 12
                      echo "Today Event";
                        

                        
                    } else if($diff_days == -0){ //condition to check date from April 11 - April  12
                       echo "Ongoing Event";
                       

                    }

                }elseif($diff > 1 && $diff > -1 || $diff == 0){ //condition to check date from April 12 - April 18 or April 9 - April 14
              
                   echo "Ongoing Event";
            
              
                }else{ // condtion to check the date above the current date
                  echo "Upcomming Event";
              
                  
                  
                } ?>
```

**If Any one who can Simplify These codes will be great helpful**

Thank You